# sql, get date within a range but also using getDate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get dates that are between some dates, but I need to use the GETDATE function as well, since it has to be from 01 December last year to 31 march of the current year
I just can concatenate the dates and put them in a between statement

[edit]
I'm using sql server and the code I have is the following

```
select c.nombre, p.folio, pg.fecha, pg.monto
from Cliente c, Contratante ct, póliza p, Pago pg
where c.IdCli = ct.IdCli and p.IdCli = ct.IdCli and p.folio = pg.folio
```

I get the following results

```
Jorge González  300 2018-12-20 00:00:00.000 10000,00
Jorge González  300 2019-06-30 00:00:00.000 7000,00
Alejandro Lara  310 2018-12-30 00:00:00.000 8000,00
Francisco Hernández 320 2019-03-31 00:00:00.000 5000,00
Marcela Ocampo  330 2019-06-30 00:00:00.000 5000,00
```

I want only to get those between 2018-12-01 and 2019-03-31 
but I need to do it using the current year as a reference

Comment: Which database are you using Sql server or mysql ? and a Design for the table and maybe some data as well are very usefull finally how should the result look like like

Comment: @nbk mysql does not have getdate(), ms sql server does.

Comment: You can use getdate() and dateadd() in SQL Server. You can convert to date time type using convert(). You can use month() to get the month and year() to get the year from getdate().

Comment: I uploaded some information as an edit

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will get you '20181201':

```
select convert(char(4), year(getdate()) - 1) + '12' + '01'
```

and '20190331':

```
select convert(char(4), year(getdate())) + '03' + '31'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of getdatefromparts, year and getdate:

The following gives you 2108-12-01

```
select datefromparts(year(getdate())-1,12,1)
```

The following gives you 2019-03-31

```
select datefromparts(year(getdate()),3,31)
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are static, your best bet may be to use a combination of the `extract` and `getdate` functions.

```sql
select * from my_table
where my_date between 
  convert(date, year(getdate() - 1) + '-12-01') 
  and convert(date, year(getdate()) + '-03-01')
```

Comment: `EXTRACT()` in SQL Server? It's available in MySQL not SQL Server.

Comment: @Sami: Doh! You're absolutely right. I work with a bunch of databases and got a bit mixed up. Thanks. :)